# Multiple CASEs in WHERE Clause with ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm trying to write a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause that goes something like this.
My problem is that at the end of this I want to say `ELSE CalendarQuarter IN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)`. So if none of these conditions are met, do something else. I can't figure out how to add this `ELSE` statement.

```
AND CalendarQuarter in
(
    /*March, June, Sep 2010 Metcard*/
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6,9)  THEN @Q1  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6)  THEN @Q2  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3)  THEN @Q3  END),

    /*March, June, Sep 2010 Metcard/Myki*/  
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6,3)  THEN @Q4  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6)  THEN @Q3  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9)  THEN @Q2  END),

    /*March, June, Sep 2013 Metcard/Myki*/
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6,9)  THEN @Q1  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6)  THEN @Q2  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013
        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3)  THEN @Q3  END),

    /*March, June, Sep 2013 Myki*/  
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6,3)  THEN @Q4  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6)  THEN @Q3  END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
        AND @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9)  THEN @Q2  END),

    /*ELSE....IN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)*/

)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your post, but it sounds like you want to add another case statement. ELSE shouldn't have any conditions, it is used to catch everything which doesn't match any of the conditions in case statement it is attached to.

e.g.
the column foo can contain 1, 2, 3 or 4, and we want to set the column to a, b, c or c respectively. We have the following case statement

```
CASE
    WHEN foo = 1
        THEN 'a'
    WHEN foo = 2
        THEN 'b'
    ELSE 'c'
END
```

We don't need to add a case for 3 or 4 because they do not match 1 or 2, so they will be handled by the else, setting them to c.

If you are trying to add another condition to the else statement, you can just use another case statement inside the else. In this case, we want to translate the value of foo 3 or 4 into x or y.

```
CASE
    WHEN foo = 1
        THEN 'a'
    WHEN foo = 2
        THEN 'b'
    ELSE CASE
            WHEN foo = 3
                THEN 'x'
            WHEN foo = 4
                THEN 'y'
            ELSE NULL
        END
END
```

Of course, you can use any values you want, you don't need to be evaluating a single column in the condition.

Edit: I have created an example using your case statement. It has a second case statement in your ELSE which allows you to add conditions to the else.

```
AND CalendarQuarter IN
                    (
                    CASE 
                        /*March, June, Sep 2010 Metcard*/
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6,9)  
                            THEN @Q1
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6)  
                            THEN @Q2
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3)  
                            THEN @Q3

                        /*March, June, Sep 2013 Metcard/Myki*/
                        CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6,3)  
                            THEN @Q4
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6)  
                            THEN @Q3
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9)  
                            THEN @Q2

                        /*March, June, Sep 2013 Metcard/Myki*/
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6,9)  
                            THEN @Q1
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3,6)  
                            THEN @Q2
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (3)  
                            THEN @Q3

                        /*March, June, Sep 2013 Myki*/ 
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6,3)  
                            THEN @Q4
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9,6)  
                            THEN @Q3
                        WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 
                                        AND @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
                                        AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) IN (9)  
                            THEN @Q2

                        ELSE CASE
                                WHEN [YOUR CONDITION HERE] IN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)
                                    THEN [SOME RESULT]
                                END
                    END
                    )
```

The above statement will return as soon as a condition is met. An alternative is using your original case statement, but instead of using else, you use an inverse of the conditions above. e.g.

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013
        THEN CASE 
                WHEN @ticketing_system = 'myki' 
                    THEN CASE
                            WHEN DATEPART(mm,@year_end) NOT IN (9,6,3)
                                THEN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)
                        END
                WHEN @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki' 
                    THEN CASE
                            WHEN DATEPART(mm,@year_end) NOT IN (3,6,9)
                                THEN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)
                        END
             END
    WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010
        THEN CASE
                WHEN @ticketing_system = 'metcard/myki'
                    THEN CASE
                            WHEN DATEPART(mm,@year_end) NOT IN (9,6,3)
                                THEN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)
                        END
                WHEN @ticketing_system = 'metcard' 
                    THEN CASE
                            WHEN DATEPART(mm,@year_end) NOT IN (3,6,9)
                                THEN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4)
                         END
            END
END
```

Comment: with this code, wouldn't it stop once it found one of the statements to be TRUE? For example, if the very fist statement is true, then I still want it to evaluate the second statement, because it's possible that it is also true.

Comment: You're right, this will only match on a single record. The easiest solution I can suggest is writing a final case statement which is the inverse of the case statements which proceed it. Alternatively, you could use the results of the case statement as a column in the query, then wrap it in a select testing for null. I have edited my answer to add an example of a case statement which has the inverse. I think I got each condition, but you might want to do a quick sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you avoiding the case clauses and try by using:

```
WHERE (DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2010
AND @ticketing_system         = 'metcard'
AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end)   IN (3,6,9)
AND CalendarQuarter          IN (@Q1))
OR 
(DATEPART(yy,@year_end)    = 2010
AND @ticketing_system         = 'metcard'
AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end)   IN (3,6)
AND CalendarQuarter          IN (@Q2))
..................................
OR 
(DATEPART(yy,@year_end)    = 2013
AND @ticketing_system         = 'myki'
AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end)   IN (9)
AND CalendarQuarter          IN(@Q2) )
OR 
(CalendarQuarter          IN (@Q1,@Q2,@Q3,@Q4))
```